# Как реализовать локализацию через URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

На сайте реализовано три локализации. **ru**, **de** и **en**. Английский является основным. 
Пользователь первый раз заходит на главную страницу сайта по адресу `http://mysite.com/`, отправляя запрос `Accept-Language: fr;q=0.9`. Так как французкий не реализован, то его перенаправляет на английскую версию `http://mysite.com/en/`. На сайте есть форма поиска которая отправляет POST запрос на URL `/search`. На сервере отсутсвует сохранение состояния(сессии и аналоги)

Пробовал реализовать через **.htaccess**, но не знаю как правильно реализовать генерацию URL для форм и как передавать локаль. А также как подставить локаль в URL, если пользователь перейдет по ссылке без локали `http://mysite.com/faq`

```
RewriteEngine On

#Локаль по умолчанию
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^(ru|de) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /ru/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /de/ [L,R=302]

#Перенаправлять все запросы на единую точку входа
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью PHP

```
class T {

    public static $lang;

    public static function init(array $languages, $defaultLanguage, $delimiter = '/') {
        $url = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $delimiter);
        $parts = explode($delimiter, $url);
        $lang = array_shift($parts);

        if (!in_array($lang, $languages)) {
            $prefLocales = array_reduce(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']), function ($res, $el) {
                list($l, $q) = array_merge(explode(';q=', $el), [1]);
                $res[$l] = (float)$q;

                return $res;
            }, []);

            arsort($prefLocales);
            $lang = $defaultLanguage;

            foreach (array_keys($prefLocales) as $l) {
                if (in_array($l, $languages)) {
                    $lang = $l;
                    break;
                }
            }

            header("Location: {$delimiter}{$lang}{$delimiter}{$url}");

            exit();
        }

        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $delimiter . implode($delimiter, $parts);
        self::$lang = $lang;
    }
}
```

Все запросы направляются на единую точку входа

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Все ссылки правятся с помощью JS, либо дописываются на беке

```
<?php T::init(['en','de','ru'], 'en'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= T::getLang() ?>">
<body>
<form action="/<?= T::getLang() ?>/search" method="POST" >
     <input type="text" name="term"/>
     <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```